# Name of this "cut 'n slide" fractal?

Tags: fractals

[image]

Can you identify this fractal--if in fact is has a name--based either upon its look or on the method of its generation? It's created in [this short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug9fhgy9N60).

It looks similar to a dragon fractal, but I don't think they are the same. Help, please?

Comment: The [twindragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#Twindragon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the [twindragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#Twindragon).  It is a two-dimensional self-similar set.  That is it is composed of two smaller copies of itself scaled by the factor $\sqrt{2}$ as shown here:

[image]

Using this self-similarity, one can construct a tiling of the plane with fractal boundary.  Analysis of the fractal dimension of the boundary is also possible, but it's a bit harder.

It's all truly great fun!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I look forward to sharing the video and some information about the twindragon in an upcoming post on Math Munch.

Comment: @JustinLanier Sounds awesome - have fun!